# Recommended filesystem for MySQL (xfs vs ext4)

Tags: mysql, filesystems, ext4, xfs

Setting up a MySQL 5.5 server, and wondering what the recommended filesystem is? `ext4` or `xfs`? Running `InnoDB` and 40% writes 60% reads. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it makes much of a difference, seeing as InnoDB more or less just creates one giant file on the filesystem. I imagine that almost any filesystem other than a copy-on-write filesystem like zfs or Btrfs is pretty good at reading and writing byte ranges of a file on a filesystem that contains just a few dozen files. Note that you can also put InnoDB on a raw partition (no filesystem), though that doesn't seem to be a popular thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Although XFS is good, in practice I've found ext4 to be slightly faster.

I developed an application recently and compared the I/O performance of both and found ext4 to be slightly quicker for my application which was really just opening and reading whole files into memory.  Seeking around those files which a DB will do may yield different results.  However, I suspect in practice you may not really notice.

One thing that I recall reading about when testing various filesystems out for the app I was developing, is that XFS can screw up rather badly when it goes wrong.  Something about filling files with zeros.  I'm not sure where I read this, but another search yielded a link with some comments about this happening to them.  http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1169535

Therefore I'd opt for ext4 since it's better supported, quite fast and is the default on most linux distro's and now quite mature and stable.

btrfs is getting there but but still doesn't seem to be ready for production yet.
If ZFS was a real contender on Linux I'd recommend that over ext4.